# is there any data packet format in standard bluetooth characteristics?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Is there any data packet format in standard bluetooth characteristics? Because I used bloodPressure meter from omron and A&D Medical, these two have the same standard characteristics. But data positions are not equal. And there is no good documents I found on the internet. Even from bluetooth.org. So is there any perticular data position format of the standard ble characteristics?
In the XML document of blood pressure,  I found that the data is available or not is mentioned or what kind of data is available. But not the positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [specifications](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/) provided by the Bluetooth SIG. The Document for the Blood Pressure Service (BLS v1.1) clearly describes the service and its characteristics of the standard.

Some of the characteristics are optional or depend on another to be there. You can find this information at the top of chapter 3.

Sometimes even characteristics do have optional fields, but this is also well documented.